# travis gcc build failling - 'codecvt' file not found

Tags: c++11, gcc, travis-ci

I am trying to add automated build to my [github project](https://github.com/FFMG/myoddweb.any), but I get the error `fatal error: 'codecvt' file not found`

This is what my travis.yml file looks like

```
sudo: required
dist: trusty
language: cpp
compiler:
  - clang
env: 
  - LLVM_VERSION=3.8.1
os:
  - linux
script:
  - bash build.sh
```

I have also tried with `gcc` but neither seems to work.

After a bit of digging around it seems that gcc 5 added support for this c++11 feature, but it looks like travis does not, (yet?) support this.

Any suggestions on how I could get it to work? Maybe another compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution bu piecing together various hints from sites.

```
language: cpp
sudo: required

script:
  - sudo unlink /usr/bin/gcc && sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-6 /usr/bin/gcc
  - sudo unlink /usr/bin/g++ && sudo ln -s /usr/bin/g++-6 /usr/bin/g++
  - gcc --version
  - bash build.sh

addons:
  apt:
    sources:
    - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
    packages:
    - gcc-6
    - g++-6
```

See the working [.travis.yml](https://github.com/FFMG/myoddweb.any/blob/master/.travis.yml)

Comment: I'm facing the same issue here https://github.com/fnc12/sqlite_orm . Can you explain the meaning of your fix please?

Comment: @fnc12 It's GCC upgrade to get newer version that supports codectv

Comment: @MartinDvorak I've just switched on `osx` and everything works fine